# SVG path get relative click position

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I'm using [Angular SVG round progress bar](http://crisbeto.github.io/angular-svg-round-progressbar/) for a music player. I want the seek to specific position functionality for which I've been trying to get the mouse click x and y co-ordinates. I get them but I don't know how to map the x,y co-ordinates to the progress. Can anyone help with that here?
[The demo code](http://play.ionic.io/app/55cc4462c1ff)

Edit 1:

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
console.log(svg);
// Create an SVGPoint for future math
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();

// Get point in global SVG space
function cursorPoint(evt){
  pt.x = evt.clientX; pt.y = evt.clientY;
  return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
 }

 svg.addEventListener('mousedown',function(evt){
 var loc = cursorPoint(evt);
  // Use loc.x and loc.y here
   // console.log(Math.sqrt((100-loc.x)*(100-loc.x) + (100-loc.y)*    (100-loc.y)));
  console.log(Math.sqrt((100-loc.x)*(100-loc.x) + (100-loc.y)*(100-loc.y)) > 93 && Math.sqrt((100-loc.x)*(100-loc.x) + (100-loc.y)*(100-loc.y)) <100);
 console.log(loc);
},false);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code you have already.

Comment: @Sam I just added the link, please check

Comment: @RobertLongson This is a how-to question. If you look at the demo I attached, I simply want to be able to click at any point on the path and update the progress bar's position according to that

Comment: OK, step 1 add an onclick event handler to the element you want to click on.

Comment: @RobertLongson After 2 days, I'm done with the step1. What's next?

Comment: @RobertLongson please see edit 1. This is how I'm checking if the point clicked is on the 'outer ring' of the circle. I'm having trouble with coming up with a co-ordinate system that translates click points on the 'outer' ring to a progress. Poor maths you know

Comment: That looks about right. If it's not you should create a runnable testcase so we can see why not. A stack snippet or a jsfiddle or something similar.

Comment: That looks and acts right but that just tells me if the user clicked on the 'outer ring/progress ring'. If you check the demo link in my questions you'd see a progress bar. I need to translate these click points to the progress bar points.